# Fatal error: Call to a member function run() on null in {path to the test file}

Tags: php, phpunit, migration, phinx

I am using PHPUnit 5.7.23 and phinx 0.9.1,

```
public function setUp(){
        $this->phinx = new PhinxApplication;
        $this->phinx->setAutoExit(false);
        $this->phinx->run(new StringInput('migrate'), new NullOutput);
        $this->phinx->run(new StringInput('seed:run'), new NullOutput);
    }


 public function tearDown(){

    $this->phinx->run(new StringInput('rollback -t 0'), new NullOutput);

}
```

This it the code of my test file , every time when i add

```
 public function testExampleFunction(){


        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
```

it fails on the line :

> $this->phinx->run(new StringInput('rollback -t 0'), new NullOutput);

with the errror :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function run() on null in {path to the
>   test file}

when i change this:

```
 public function tearDown()
    {

        if (!empty($this->phinx)) {
            $this->phinx->run(new StringInput('rollback -t 0'), new NullOutput);
        }

    }
```

it passes but since there wasn't rollback, my next tests had crashed

Comment: *$this->phinx* seems to be *null*, like not properly initialised as instance of *PhinxApplication*. Can you please debug if the *setup* was called before your *tearDown()* method?

Comment: yeah it is called before the tearDown() and it even completes : 
`$this->phinx->run(new StringInput('migrate'), new NullOutput);
        $this->phinx->run(new StringInput('seed:run'), new NullOutput);`

Comment: just to add that it works for other tests configured the same way, just in this test it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using namespacing (PSR-4) ?
If so, you should have this line of code:

> `use Phinx\Console\PhinxApplication;`